# React-google-charts. There are no availability to remove gradient in Geo-chart

Tags: reactjs, react-google-charts

I want to set up only 4 colors for all country in Geo Chart

```
const colors = ["#D7D8D9", "#FCB8C9", "#FE557F", "#661529"]
```

Geo - chart always shows some gradient for each country from first color to last color by range

I want to remove this gradient and I want to show country on the world map with specific color by range

For example -

```
const options = {
    colorAxis: {
        ranges: [
                {
                    min: 2,
                    max: 498,
                    color: "#D7D8D9",
                },
                {
                    min: 498,
                    max: 995,
                    color: "#D7D8D9",
                },
                {
                    min: 995,
                    max: 1491,
                    color: "#D7D8D9",
                },
                {
                    min: 1491,
                    max: 1987,
                    color: "#D7D8D9",
                },
            ],
        },
        legend: "none",
    };
```

This variant doesn't work and I don't know how I can do it

Also I tried next -

```
const options = {
        colorAxis: {
            ranges: [
                {
                    min: 2,
                    max: 498,
                    color: color[0],
                },
                {
                    min: 498,
                    max: 995,
                    color:  color[1],
                },
                {
                    min: 995,
                    max: 1491,
                    color: "color[2]",
                },
                {
                    min: 1491,
                    max: 1987,
                    color: color[3]",
                },
            ],
        },
        legend: "none",
    };
```

It doesn't work as expected